# Right-to-left columns (and tables) in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, right-to-left

I'm writing a document in Arabic, a language that is written right to left. I have found the right-to-left direction button and enabled it throughout the document.

Now, I would like to use two columns. The text should flow in the right column first, and then the left column. However, currently, it is doing the opposite: the text is flowing in the left column first, and then the right column.

Likewise, I would like to have right-to-left tables, where the first column is the rightmost column, and the second colum is the second rightmost column, and so forth.

How do I enable right-to-left columns in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Click the "Format" menu, and then "Page style..."
2. Click the "Page" tab within the dialog
3. Select "Right-to-left (horizontal)" in the "Text direction" section.

[image: Screenshot]

This works for both columns, and tables.